# Export unrecognized pages abbyy flexicapture

Tags: abbyy

I have an Abbyy flexicapture for invoices project and I need to export unrecognized pages before the verification phase knowing that I am newby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "Unknown Page" document definition and load a flexilayout with no header or footer. You can then export the document etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just create new Export stage in the workflow and do the following:

- in General tab check "Restrict set of Document Definitions being used" and select "unknown document" and "unprocessed document"
- in Entry Conditions tab check "Always"
- in Exit Routes tab set Next Stage -> Custom -> Processed